I have solved:- TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
This error occurred because of attempting to pickle an object that does not support pickling, likely due to a non-trivial cinit method.

Could you please post the solution as an answer below and remove it from the question?

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

We modified the way we save and load the FAISS index to avoid using pickle directly on objects that do not support it. Instead, we used FAISS methods to save and load the index directly from files.
def get_vector_store(text_chunks):
    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")
    vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    vector_store.save_local("faiss_index")

def load_vector_store():
    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")
    vector_store = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)
    return vector_store
This approach ensures that the FAISS index is saved and loaded correctly without relying on pickling, which resolves the TypeError: no default reduce due to non-trivial cinit error.

